# Getting base Line of PostGIS skeleton

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql, ogr

I'm interested in using OGR/GDAL, PostGIS, or QGIS in order to achieve the following:

Working from the [PostGIS docs](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_StraightSkeleton.html), how would one further simplify this line to the middle line? I've tried utilizing the ST_Simplify function as well as the ST_SimplifyVW and it doesn't seem to have any affect. Here is an example of what is depicted on the docs:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 190 190, 10 190, 10 10, 190 10, 190 20, 160 30, 60 30, 60 130, 190 140, 190 190 ))',4326)
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT st_simplifyvw(ST_StraightSkeleton(st_union(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 190 190, 10 190, 10 10, 190 10, 190 20, 160 30, 60 30, 60 130, 190 140, 190 190 ))',4326))),10);
```

And basically what I'm trying to extract is the black line by trimming the branches off (so to speak):

[image]

Comment: Some previous takes: https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools/geoserver/2021/09/26/Centrelines-part2.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921826/how-do-i-calculate-the-medial-axis-for-a-2d-vector-shape https://github.com/MapServer/MapServer/pull/5854

Comment: For the above example, this custom function may work: ST_LongestAxisPolygonsFromVoronoiDiagrams_gs (but its logic will only work for simple polygonal objects that fit within the bounding box)....

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach to "trim the branches" could be by longitude but is not a complete solution.

```
with lines as (
SELECT 
st_subdivide(
st_straightskeleton( ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 190 190, 10 190, 10 10, 190 10, 190 20, 160 30, 60 30, 60 130, 190 140, 190 190 ))',4326)), 5) segment
,st_length(
st_subdivide(
st_straightskeleton( ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 190 190, 10 190, 10 10, 190 10, 190 20, 160 30, 60 30, 60 130, 190 140, 190 190 ))',4326)), 5)) longitude ) 
select segment from lines where longitude>20;
```

Comment: Thanks Pepe, but this will not suffice in this scenario, I think I may look into the OGR centerline library to accomplish this.